# Twitter4j twitter Rate Limit Error Code 88

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter4j

I am Working to Android App

I can get just 180 ID Twitter send me Error Rate Limit exceeded Error Code 88

This is my Code

```
                       idsFollower = twitter1.getFriendsIDs(cursor);
                       for (long id : idsFollower.getIDs()) {


                           User user = twitter1.showUser(id);
                           if(user!=null){

                           Log.e("User Name's  ", user.getScreenName()+Sayac);

                           Sayac++;
                           Followers.add(user.getId());

                           }
                       }
                   } while ((cursor = idsFollower.getNextCursor()) != 0);
```

Some App dont waiting for loading User Data. How do they do it ?  can anyone help me ?

Comment: "Some App dont waiting for loading User Data" Maybe those others app use another methods like GNIP (that is paid)

Comment: I am trying too GNIP but . I get error again. I Think its have a special Metod...